# usort using specified array not working if not enough values are specified

Tags: php, usort

I have a multidimensional array `$itemsToSort[$totalItems][0]` that shall be sorted with respect to an array `$sortOrder`. It works very well if all or almost all items are included in `$sortOrder` but not if just a few are specified. The code is as below, I want the items that don't match to be placed at the end of `$itemsToSort[$totalItems][]`.

```
    usort($itemsToSort, function($a, $b) use ($sortOrder){
       $valA = array_search($a[0], $sortOrder);
       $valB = array_search($b[0], $sortOrder);
       if ($valA === false)
          return -1;
       if ($valB === false)
          return 0;
       if ($valA > $valB)
          return 1;
       if ($valA < $valB)
          return -1;
    return 0;
    });
```

Comment: You can replace the last two if's with `return $valA - $valB;`

Comment: That gave me the same result. The strange thing is that the code works with all items included in the $sortOrder array.

Comment: You need to return `1` when `$a` is in `$sortOrder` but `$b` isn't.

Comment: Should if ($valB === false)
          return 0; be replaced with if ($valB === false)
          return 1; ?

Comment: I think that's the fix, try it and see.

Comment: The question could use some sample data & results (both desired and actual), but other than that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your final `return 0;` says *do not change order*. But if you want to place elements at the end of array, return `1` instead

Comment: The final `return 0;` is for elements that are both in `$sortOrder` and have equal sort orders, so `0` is correct.

Comment: It's the first `return 0;` that needs to be changed, not the last.

Answer (score 0):

The code has been modified to

```
    if ($valA === false)
        return -1;
    if ($valB === false)
        return 1;
    return $valA - $valB;
    return 0;
    });
```

This works for sorting the matching items so that they appear in order. Items that don't match are placed above the matches, they are desired to appear below. How can I change?